# set of word from the same line to several lines in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my line:

```
^MClone: 10% done.^MClone: 11% done.^MClone: 12% done.^MClone: 13% done.^MClone: 14% done.^MClone: 15% done.^MClone: 16% done.
```

I would like to split each `Clone: xx%` per line

As expected result:

```
Clone: 10%
Clone: 11%
Clone: 12%
etc..
```

each line should contains each pourcentage instead of having all in only one line.

Comment: Does your input data contain _literal_ sequences of `^M`, or are the `^M` instances representations of _underlying `\r` (CR) characters_, as you'd get with `cat -v`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`. `^M` is represented by `\r`:

```
sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' -e 's/ done\.//g' file
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your own answer suggests that you assume that the input contains _literal `^M` sequences_, whereas choroba assumes that they're just _representations_ of _underlying `\r` (CR) characters_, as you would get with `cat -v`. While choroba's interpretation strikes me as more likely, we won't know for sure unless the OP clarifies.

Comment: OK, I'll delete my comments as well (in a few minutes) - I've asked the OP for clarification instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -o 'Clone: [0-9]*%' file
Clone: 10%
Clone: 11%
Clone: 12%
Clone: 13%
Clone: 14%
Clone: 15%
Clone: 16%
```

This looks for strings on the format `Clone: <numbers>%` and prints them.

From `man grep`:

> **-o**, --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
>   such part on a separate output line.

Comment: Good one. Super it worked out at first attempt! Cheers and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work,

```
sed 's/\^M//g;s/done.//g;s/% /%\n/g' file
```